# Content jumps up when menu becomes fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sticky, mmenu

I have a menu bar that I'd like to stick to the top of the browser window once it hits the top. I've more or less done this but the content below it jumps up when the position changes.

I tried using `position: sticky` with a Polyfill, which worked well. But I'm also using a slide-out nav plugin (mmenu) which means when the menu slides out the menu bar flickers as it has known issues with sticky/fixed menus. However using `position: fixed` instead of `sticky` seems to prevent that annoying issue.

Here's what I have so far on a CodePen: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/YeavrX

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason this is happening is because position: fixed takes that header out of the flow, thus the content shifts up to fill that void space. You could put a padding-top equal to the height of the fixed position header to get around this, if the height is not dynamic depending on screen resolution

Comment: I'm not sure I'll always know the height. There is a thin banner about the header which isn't fixed and that _could_ go onto 1 or 2 lines. I tried getting the height of the header in the JS to add it onto the content as padding but that still causes a jump. :/

Comment: Were you accounting for padding, or just the height?

Comment: I've tried `height` and `outerHeight` but no luck. I don't think it's applying the padding actually.